# Blazor isolated CSS files not working (sometimes) and how isolated is <style> element

Tags: blazor, blazor-client-side

I have been having a problem with foo.razor.css that works sometimes, then it doesn't.  Yesterday I have an isolated CSS file working, then today it didn't see it.  Didn't shutdown VS when I had the issue, but did try and restart it with no joy.  I tried a solution clean without success.

Does anyone have this problem?

How isolated is  element in Blazor?  I am assuming it is merged into the global CSS space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Happens to me sometimes. It can get cached in browser, then force reload the page to make sure it's dowloaded.

If you inspect the element in browser, do you see what css file overrides your style?

Also, the order of css links in index.html or _Host.html files does matter. From the element inspection info, you should see where the conflict comes from.

Comment: It never crossed my mind that it could be cached.  Thank you.